# Calling updated on chart

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, chartkick

I'm rendering charts of my vuex store. Before When my data would change the charts would update automatically, now I see the value changing in my store but the charts aren't updating. I'm not sure how to call an update on the chart.

```
<template>
 <swiper :options="swiperOption">
    <swiper-slide v-for="(photon,key) in this.$store.state.photons" 
 :key='key'>           
  <line-chart :library="chartOptions" v-if="photon.SF.showCharts":data="photon.SF.rbChannelOverlay"></line-chart> 

  </swiper-slide>
 </swiper>
</template>
```

Comment: how are you doing that update in vuex store action or mutation?

Comment: by an event listener in the store that pushes the data to my photon objects